# Why is each wavelength of light diffracted differently?

Tags: optics, waves

> [image]

Why is do we see different colors, instead of white spots like in the middle?

Why is the single slit less intense the further away from the middle you look?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the wavelengths are different for different colours, using the relation between diffraction strength as $S=S(h/\lambda)$ ($h$ is slit size and $\lambda$ is wavelenght), it is apparent that when you keep the slit size constant and compare the different wavelengths then diffraction strength changes so does the separation between the colours emerges. The equation can be driven by the propagation of waves.